# python unpacking for loop

Tags: python, python-2.7

I'm using Python 2.7 and I just have a simple question in my code i have

```
from sys import argv
script, first, second, third = [argv, "bike","car","lemon"]
```

I know i can just say

```
print(script)
```

or

```
print(first)
```

and it will print on a line
but is there a way to print this in a for loop where it would each of the values
i know the logic would be something like

```
for x,y in ?:
print(y)
```

Since this argument with the values isn't named i don't know what to put for in my question mark.

Comment: What do you expect to be in `x` and `y`?

Comment: for example i would think the x would be script, and y would be argv- its value.

Answer (score 4):

You could simply create a `tuple/list` of objects iterate over it and print the current element.

```
for element in (script, first, second, third):
    print element

>>> obj1
    obj2
    ...
```

However if you want to print all the objects in same line then you may use a `,` comma after the print statement:

```
for element in (script, first, second, third):
    print element, 

>>> obj1 obj2 ...
```

Comment: Thanks i'm new to python and I just wasn't sure how to print it because my list didn't have a name. Works Great, thanks again

Answer (score 2):

You can just use join if you just want to print the elements from the list:

```
 print "\n".join(["argv", "bike","car","lemon"])
 argv
 bike
 car
 lemon
```

If you want to print the unpacked elements just put them is a list or tuple and do the same but if you are not using the variables anywhere that is pointless.

Or import `print_function`:

```
from __future__ import print_function
print(*["argv", "bike", "car", "lemon"],sep="\n")
argv
bike
car
lemon
```

You can pass any separator you want or none at all and each element will be printed on the same line with a space between:

```
print(*["argv", "bike", "car", "lemon"])
argv bike car lemon
```

To unpack all the elements in a loop the elements would have to be in a container inside the list:

```
for a, b, c, d in [("argv", "bike", "car", "lemon")]:
    print(a, b, c, d)
```